# iPhone SDK on iBook G4 (PowerPC G4) with OS X 10.5.8?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, powerpc

Is that possible to install xCode and iPhone SDK on my iBook G4 with PowerPC G4 CPU and MAC OS X 10.5.8? I am trying to install several versions but not successfull

Comment: Very old versions, such as the iPhone 2.x SDK, contained PPC code, but the installation needed to be copied from an Intel Mac.  All recent versions of the iOS SDK and Xcode are Intel-only.

Comment: I wonder how horribly slow Qemu will be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The SDK is Intel-only. It contains no PowerPC code.

It's time for you to get a new Mac. Sorry.